# Why would Groovy apply an AST transformation twice if a method has parameters?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm running a small test using Groovy/Grails v5 to apply an AST transformation to a controller method.
The method takes a single parameter, to represent a typical command object.
I've added some logging to the AST transform class so within the visit() method, I can see that it is being applied.

If the controller method has no parameters,  then I see the transform is being applied, no issue.
However, if I add the parameter, the command object, to the method then I see my logging output twice.

The first time it's applied I can see the expected output that tells me it's being applied to the method, and that it's detected the parameter.

It then gets called a second time and tells me that it's being applied BUT this time it doesn't see any parameters.

This is the visit() method:

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.CANONICALIZATION)
public class AjaxResponseASTTransformation extends AbstractAstTransformation {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AjaxResponseASTTransformation.class);

  @Override
  public void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source) {

    final MethodNode methodNode = (MethodNode) nodes[1];
    log("detected AjaxResponse annotation for method " + methodNode.getName());

    final Parameter[] parameters = methodNode.getParameters();

    if (parameters != null) {
      for (Parameter parameter : parameters) {
        log("Found Parameter : " + parameter.getName());
      }
      if (parameters.length == 0) {
        log("No parameters present - what gives??");
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the controller method:

```
 @AjaxResponse
    def index(MyCommand myCommand) { render "" }
```

Building this project yields the following output:

```
20:01:00.537 [/127.0.0.1:51713 to /127.0.0.1:51712 workers] INFO mypackage.AjaxResponseASTTransformation - detected AjaxResponse annotation for method index
20:01:00.538 [/127.0.0.1:51713 to /127.0.0.1:51712 workers] INFO mypackage.AjaxResponseASTTransformation - Found Parameter : myCommand
20:01:00.538 [/127.0.0.1:51713 to /127.0.0.1:51712 workers] INFO mypackage.AjaxResponseASTTransformation - detected AjaxResponse annotation for method index
20:01:00.538 [/127.0.0.1:51713 to /127.0.0.1:51712 workers] INFO mypackage.AjaxResponseASTTransformation - No parameters present - what gives??
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour as to why it's being applied twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a controller action like this:

```
def index(MyCommand myCommand) { 
  render "" 
}
```

At compile time we generate a no-arg version of that method which looks something like this:

```
def index() { 
  MyCommand c = new MyCommand()
  bindData c, request
  // subject c to dependency injection here, code ommitted

  // this call to validate is only generated if `MyCommand` is validateable...
  c.validate()

  // this will call your method
  index(c)
}
```

Because of that, there are 2 methods in the class named `index` even though you only wrote one.

At [grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/grails/compiler/web/ControllerActionTransformer.java#L395](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/8bb3303a6343d81b18d937c4ed9841e254c24809/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/grails/compiler/web/ControllerActionTransformer.java#L395) is the part of the controller action transformer which is copying your annotation to the no-arg method.

This by the way is the reason that method overloading is not supported for controller action methods.  We have to generate the no-arg one with the same name, so you can't have 2 action methods with the same name that accept different parameters.  We generate a compiler error indicating that when that scenario is encountered.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the explanation.    It seems that the first time it's calling visit() then it's picking up my implementation,  and the second time it's the no-arg version.   Do you know if this order of execution is guaranteed?

Comment: "Do you know if this order of execution is guaranteed?" - I don't.  Sorry about that.  I would use care when transforming controller actions, in part because of the method indirection I described in the answer above.  If you have a good understanding of what the core transformations are doing, that will be good. If you have any questions or concerns about any of it, reach out and we can get someone on a call or whatever will help.  I know you know how to find us. Good luck!